# Powershell script 'Basic Authentication' wont run on Server VM due to group policies. How can i use OAuth to bypass this

Tags: powershell, oauth, exchange-server

I have a PowerShell script that connects to Exchange using 'Basic Authentication', which works on my local machine, but the code needs to run on a server vm.

The server doesn't allow basic authentication and Ops wont let me change it with a bypass or overwriting basic auth. I've also tried changing it through RedEdit but I've also been block by ops. I just need some help re-writing the line of code for OAuth or a some links to how to connect to exchange and release quarantine messages.

Below is the code I was given to use for basic auth.
How can I do the same with OAuth

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/' -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting here since the comment section would not hold this text.

This is not a PowerShell code problem or error you are requesting assistance. 
You don't say what version of Exchange, you are targeting, etc...

You are trying to circumvent corporate policy. In most companies, that generates an RPE (resume producing event) if you are discovered trying / doing this. This is not a PowerShell code issue, but a physical / logical restriction your employer has in place. Only your org knows why they are doing this, and you need to try to convince them otherwise.

So, maybe this is an off topic thing, since you are literally asking us to help you break your corporate risk policy.

All that being said, even MS says Basic Auth should not be used, and is going away. ***How to you know OAuth is enabled, before you go down this path?***  or even can be, depending on your Exchange version.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/default-settings-for-exchange-virtual-directories-exchange-2013-help
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/clients/default-virtual-directory-settings?view=exchserver-2019

Anyway, Authentication for PowerShell, in New-PSSession is shown here:

> [New-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/New-PSSession?view=powershell-5.1#-authentication)
>
> -Authentication  Specifies the mechanism that is used to authenticate the user's credentials. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

- Default
- Basic
- Credssp
- Digest
- Kerberos
- Negotiate
- NegotiateWithImplicitCredential

> The default value is Default.

Getting OAuth for Exchange specific sessions is documented here (there are many steps to get this going):

[Acquiring OAuth2 access tokens for automating Exchange Management Shell cmdlets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2018/09/07/acquiring-oauth2-access-tokens-for-automating-exchange-management-shell-cmdlets/)

[Test-OAuthConnectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/test-oauthconnectivity?view=exchange-ps)

[Use OAuth on Exchange on-premises without Hybrid Modern Authentication](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/configure-hybrid-modern-authentication-for-exchange-server/)

[Using PowerShell and oAuth](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/11/02/using-powershell-and-oauth/)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response. I'm currently engaging with the security team and the reason why it cant have the admin rights is because we're using RPA and the bot account isn't allowed to have admin rights as its not a real user, but you've help point me in the right direction with the post, which is what I was looking for, Thank you.

Comment: No worries and good luck with your security team. As well all know, they are the org of 'no'. I say that as one on such teams, who always try to get them to approach things differently when responding to needs, requests, missions, etc... The real deal, is getting by-in and support from your management or up one level of them. Just make sure not to ruffle too many feathers, it can come back to bite you.  ;-}